# Authenticating websocket requests with nginx

Tags: http, authentication, nginx, websocket, request

There is a WebSocket server that I can't modify, and I don't want everyone to send requests to this. I want to add something like HTTP basic auth to the WebSocket so that it doesn't allow every request to pass through to the actual server. I am using Nginx and want to stick to it, but if there is any other program that accomplishes this, I am ok with that too.

Comment: Id use a [subrequest](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/) with a JWT which you would probably provide anyway as part of sign in, there are examples in the docs of that and using auth basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lawrence, I checked out the docs for subrequest and this works now, after writing an auth server with node.js

```
server {
    location /ws {
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the "auth" endpoint be called for each and every websocket request?